# Unix files permissions depending on path(?)

Tags: linux, centos, file-permissions

I have a directory cyanspring with a nohup.out file.

```
drwxr-xr-x 12 usr1 usr1     4096 Aug 20 13:59 cyanspring
```

Owner of the file is able to read it:

```
[root@lw414 usr1]# sudo -u usr1 ls -l cyanspring/nohup.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr1 usr1 30617 Aug 20 14:00 cyanspring/nohup.out
```

When I try to read it with another user, I get Permission denied.

```
[root@lw414 usr1]# sudo -u zabbix ls -l cyanspring/nohup.out
ls: cannot access cyanspring/nohup.out: Permission denied
```

If i go inside the directory, I am able to read the file with the same user who had "Permission Denied".

```
[root@lw414 usr1]# cd cyanspring
[root@lw414 cyanspring]# sudo -u zabbix ls -l nohup.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr1 usr1 30617 Aug 20 14:00 nohup.out
```

Absolute path doesn`t work as well.

I thought it doesn`t matter where you try to access the file from as long as you have the link and permissions. Can anybody give me a hint where I am wrong? Could it be because of outer folders permissions?

Comment: What are permissions of directory `cyanspring`? 700 or 744?

Comment: And what permissions has current directory (parent of cyanspring)?

Comment: Wow, Thank you. I`ve added x permission to the outer folder and could open the file using absolute path. Didn`t think that would matter...Got to read more about permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got "Permission denied" because user zabbix does not have search permission to `lachesis` directory.

This can be fixed by starting this command from `lachesis` directory:

```
sudo chmod go+x .
```

Permissions are calculated for each directory beginning from current directory if you give relative path, or beginning from root, if you give absolute path.